# No "SelectionChanged" option for DatePicker

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

So I am attempting to make an app with UWP, but I've hit quite a huge issue. I would like the app to do something for me when I change the date on my DatePicker. Whenever I double click on one of the Textboxes/listviews I've added on MainPage file, it creates the "SelectionChanged" function for it.

So my question is, how come it does not do the same for the DatePicker/what is the appropriate thing to put within the DatePicker tag to have a function like that? I have tried Googling around and found that there is something called "SelectedDateChanged" but even when I attempt to add it manually it doesn't show up on the list.

This is the DatePicker XAML code:

```
<DatePicker Name="dt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="36,130,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DatePicker.DateChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.datechanged) event to handle your case.

Comment: That solved it, thanks a bunch!